# Trouble fixing a detail on a Thesis template

Tags: floats

I'm currently in the process of writing a thesis and chose a template to develop it. My problem is that the precedent of captions are counting the subsections, which I don't know how to fix. For example, the figure title is "Figure 2.X : Caption Here" whereas I want it to simply be "Figure 2".

I have tried to look throughout the template definitions but I can't figure it out. I'm pretty sure it's using the caption package only.

[image: Example]

Comment: So you want continuous numbering, is that it? Figure 1: Foo. Figure 2: Bar. And so on?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you provide the example of code?

Comment: `\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}` if your class has `\chapter`s, if you only have `\section`s use `\counterwithout{figure}{section}` instead.

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SX!